# Построение приложения используя контейнер Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Стоит задача: имеются исходные файлы, необходимо собрать приложение в контейнере и получить выходные файлы обратно в файловую систему операционной системы.

Для построения контейнера используется `docker-compose`

Есть такая конфигурация:

```
volumes:
  - './src:/usr/src'   
  - './web:/usr/build'
```

Соответственно в директории `src` - исходные коды, а в директории `web` - выходные файлы.

Файлы в `/usr/src` докер отлично видит, компилирует их, складывает в `/usr/build`, однако в ОС в папке `./web` эти файлы не появляются. Что я делаю не так и как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Действительно странно. Вот что сделайте: `sudo ls -la web` на машине, а также в самом контейнере `ls -la /usr/build` после билда, вывод приложите в вопрос. Есть одна мысль на счет групп и доступа к файлам.

Comment: @TotalPusher, сделал `RUN ls -la /usr/build`, докер показал, что директория не пустая и заполнена файлами приложения. Директория `ls -la ./web` по прежнему пуста :(

Comment: @TotalPusher, на счет групп и прав - `docker-compose` если что выполняется от `sudo`

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте то, что я написал, я хочу видеть права, пользователя и группу внутри контейнера, а также права на каталог. `docker-compose` можно запускать без `sudo`, если добавить пользователя в группу docker.

Comment: @TotalPusher, в контейнере `drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root`, на хосте `drwxrwxr-x 2 user user`

Comment: @TotalPusher похоже я понял в чем дело. Сборку приложения я производил до запуска контейнера. Попробовал перенести скрипт сборки - все заработало. Спасибо за помощь)